# How to get value of multiple-file input on change with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, input

To get the value of `<input type="file" name="upload">` with jQuery, you could use `$('input').val()`.

However, using the same method to get the value of `<input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple>` (multiple-file input) only returns one file, not all of them.

Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? The answers are not helpful at all.

Comment: @Alqin Yep. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035530/how-to-get-value-of-html-5-multiple-file-upload-variable-using-jquery

Comment: but that link links to a pure-js solution, not jquery

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd That is true. But that's the closest a solution came to the question

Answer (score 2):

try console into

```
document.forms[index].elements[index].files
```

cache the values an loop through them

Answer (score 1):

I used some code from another post...

```
$('input[type=file]').val()
```

..and added the ID of each specific file input field.  The code below gets the path from the input, pulls only the filename from it and shows that value in a different field for two different file upload fields.  If you had a ton of them, you could create a loop based on this code:

```
$('#File1').change(function(){ // when you leave the File1 form field
  var filename1 = $('input[type=file][id=File1]').val().split('\\').pop(); // get just the filename
  $('#DL_Filename1').val(filename1); // and place it in the DL_Filename1 box
}); // end change

$('#File2').change(function(){ // when you leave the File2 form field
  var filename2 = $('input[type=file][id=File2]').val().split('\\').pop(); // get just the filename
  $('#DL_Filename2').val(filename2); // and place it in the DL_Filename2 box
}); // end change
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide attribution for the "code from another post..." Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because, when you use`$('input').val()` it returns the value of only the first of those inputs. You need to loop over to get the values of all of them. See the below code:

```
 var $uploads = $('input');

 $uploads.each(function() {

     console.log($(this).val());

 });
```