# how to get value of html 5 multiple file upload variable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multifile-uploader

even though i select multiple files using below html.

```
<input type="file" id="multiplefiles" name="uploadedfile[]" multiple>
```

I only get value of first file selected. i am using a simple:

```
var filelist = $("#multiplefiles").val() || [];
$.each(filelist, function(i, myfile) {
  console.log('found file '+i+' ='+myfile);
});
```

please advise how do i get list of all files...

for example selected string in the input field is:
C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Hydrangeas.jpg, C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg, C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\upload-2.txt

and from above logic i only get: following in log:

```
found file 0 =Hydrangeas.jpg
```

ty.
Rajeev

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var filelist = document.getElementById("multiplefiles").files || [];
for (var i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
    console.log('found file ' + i + ' = ' + filelist[i].name);
}
```

A working jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9KnA7/4/).

Comment: thank you very much. I also wanted to know about file sizes and by your help  - now i know i can use the .size option to get file size. thz again!!!